# How do I detect change in a Select List?

Tags: jquery

I have a button that creates 2 select lists.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("input[name$='addcriteria']").on('click', function() {
     var newrow =  $("<p>Where <select name='fieldname' class='fieldname'></select>         
     is <select name='paperSession' class='options'></select></p>");

     //--Some other codes that declares the option values of the select field--//

     });
}); //End of Document ready
```

Next, I would like to detect the actions created when I select the lists.

```
    $(".fieldname").on('change',function(){ 
        alert("testing");
    });
```

The question is: Should I be placing this action under the `$document).ready(function(){` ?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it will be good practice if you write your functions in `$(document).ready(function(){})`:

As you are adding new row dynamically try  event delegation with [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
  $(document).on('change','.fieldname',function(){ 
        alert("testing");
  });
```

**OR**

```
  $(document.body).on('change','.fieldname',function(){ 
        alert("testing");
  });
```

Here `document`/`document.body` refers to the closest parent element

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$(document).on("change",".fieldname",function(){ 
    alert("testing");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Should I be placing this action under the $(document).ready(function(){
>   ?

Yes, you need to place it inside `$(document).ready()`. Also, since the `select` elements are added dynamically, you need to use [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to register the event handler like:

```
// New way (jQuery 1.7+) - .on(events, selector, handler)
$(document).on('change', '.fieldname', function() {
    alert("testing");
});
```